# Legal Right to Own Nukes

Tags: us-constitution, weapons, second-amendment

As per the [Second Amendment](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/second_amendment) of the [United States Constitution](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/second_amendment) one has to wonder if there are any restrictions with regard to the type (or destructiveness) of arm you shall bear.

If someone could afford the bill and be in safety/inspection/regulation compliance and seek to bear the arm of [nuclear weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_weapon) one has to wonder if this would be their constitutional right.

Do people have a legal right to own nuclear weapons? Why or why not and has anyone ever taken such concerns to a court for a legal judgement on the matter?

Comment: Related: [What argument supports a right to bear arms but denies a right to bear nuclear weapons?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/6761/10)

Comment: You'd technically be permitted to own pretty much any type of destructive ordnance with a class 4 weapons permit. Of course you wouldn't ever be able to actually get or use a nuke in the first place considering that almost all radioactive material required to produce nuclear warheads is incredibly controlled. You'd have to refine your own radioactive material and produce your own weapons grade plutonium. All in all I could see someone spending more than a billion in just getting the material together to make one, but another couple hundred thousand in permits with decades of paperwork. But I g

Comment: @Jam There are no permits to own nuclear weapons in the United States. Under the Atomic Energy Act, only the Department of Energy, the Department of Defense, and their contractors can produce or possess nuclear weapons. You're trying to apply ATF rules, but those aren't the main laws relating to nukes.

Comment: Apparently there is no such thing as a class 4 weapons permit outside of fiction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Firearms_License

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_scrutiny for an explanation of the circumstances under which courts will permit fundamental rights, such as the right to bear arms, to be abridged. In this instance, their is unquestionably a "compelling governmental interest" in preventing persons from owning nukes and the court would likely uphold the ban.

Comment: See also https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/38510/how-do-originalist-interpreters-of-the-constitution-cope-with-the-2nd-amendmen  All weapons above a semi-automatic rifle require a license from the government which it is free to withhold, which is contrary to the 2nd Amendment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost certainly, there is no such right.

It's illegal under [18 USC 831](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/831) to possess "nuclear material" without specific authorization.  [18 USC 832](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/832) forbids the possession of a "radiological weapon".  If there is intent to use the device to cause death, serious bodily injury, or damage to property or the environment, that's also a violation of [18 USC 2332i](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2332i).

I don't think these laws have been explicitly tested against the Second Amendment, but related cases suggest they would hold up (if the challenge wasn't simply dismissed as frivolous).

The Second Amendment doesn't grant a blanket right to own weapons.  Federal law, 18 USC 922 (o) makes it unlawful to own a "machinegun" (as defined in the statute), and in the case of [Hollis v. Lynch](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/ca5/15-10803/15-10803-2016-06-30.html), the Fifth Circuit held that this law was constitutional, because, as they said, the Second Amendment only protects weapons that are in "common use [...] for lawful purposes like self-defense."  This case doesn't seem to have been appealed further, but the reasoning cited by the Fifth Circuit comes from the Supreme Court's opinion in [D.C. v. Heller](http://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-supreme-court/554/570.html).

If machineguns aren't in "common use", and therefore not protected, surely the same would apply to nuclear weapons.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if somebody wanted a machine gun because the mafia in his hometown were notorious for carrying them. But either way an nuke is just ridiculous.

Comment: @Joshua: That person would just be out of luck.  The machinegun law doesn't have any exceptions for such cases.

Comment: Elredge: The Court ruling explicitly depends on them not being commonly used. If this flips ...

Comment: I guess this means that at such time when "arms" are not in common use (they aren't in as common of use as they were in the 1700s) then the 2nd Amendment is moot.

Comment: "Federal law, 18 USC 922 (o) makes it unlawful to own a "machinegun"".  No it doesn't. It makes it illegal for a citizen without a FFL to own a machine gun manufactured after 1987. If a citizen has a FFL, the FFL is allowed to own as many machine guns as they please, with no date restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

Each and every time the Supreme Court has addressed the second amendment, it has upheld that it is constitutionally permissible to have prohibitions on dangerous and unusual weapons.  Nuclear weapons meet this standard.

For a prohibition to be permissible, the weapon must be **both** dangerous and unusual.

Any weapon used for offense or defense has to be dangerous.  It'd be pretty stupid to try and defend oneself with something totally incapable of inflicting pain or injury.  The historical bans referred to by SCOTUS cases narrow the concept of "dangerous" to mean:

1. the weapon has a high likelihood of injuring the person wielding the instrument AND/OR
2. the weapon, by its entire nature, indiscriminately injures or kills, and there is no manner to properly target the weapon at a specific individual or small group

Since the impact of a nuclear weapon is characterized by its rather substantial blast radius and ranges of immediate death and radiation poisoning, it is clearly an indiscriminate weapon.  As such, it meets the first half of the standard of a permissible prohibition.

Nuclear weapons are only possessed by approximately 10% of nations.  Those nations which possess these arms place them in the control of very small, specialized units.  Nuclear weapons have only been utilized twice in the history of warfare.  This qualifies them as unusual.

Comment: Those are some pretty interesting statics there you talk about. Any supporting links for further reading and such on those things which you mention. Good answer though but would be better with some source references supporting some of these things you mention. All that makes sense and even seems sensible to me though.

Comment: "Both dangerous and unusual": surely a fully automatic rifle is not dangerous by that definition, as it can be switched down to 3-shot or 1-shot mode to target an individual, and a burst on FA would seem to be suitable for targeting a small group. However I realise we are getting off the topic of nukes here.

Comment: @PaulJohnson almost a year later, but you in fact can own a fully automatic rifle

Comment: @Manchineel You *can*, provided you live in a state that permits it. According to the supreme court in *Heller* there is no constitutional right to do so. Some states have a blanket ban. Others allow it provided you have police permission, which probably translates to a blanket ban for anyone not personally acquainted with their local sheriff.

Comment: @paulJohnson "According to the supreme court in Heller there is no constitutional right to do so" the supreme court said no such thing. In DC. V. Heller, the supreme court established the test in which it is permissible to establish firearm ownership restrictions. Specifically in the context of owning and carrying a concealed pistol. Heller did not establish any such rulings about machine guns.

Comment: @tuskiomi See (2) at https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/554/570/

Comment: @PaulJohnson there is no '(2)' on that page.  I did find however- "Read in isolation, Miller’s phrase “part of ordinary military equipment” could mean that only those weapons useful in warfare are protected. That would be a startling reading of the opinion, since it would mean that the National Firearms Act’s restrictions on machineguns (not challenged in Miller) might be unconstitutional, machineguns being useful in warfare in 1939." Quite plainly saying that 'machineguns' are indeed constitutional.

Comment: @tuskiomi You need to click on "Read more...". It starts "2. Like most rights, the Second Amendment right is not unlimited."